# VBA excel for finding digit pattern in the string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I was able to write a code which finds 6 digit numbers within the string and copy it into next column but I would like to add search which also can find numbers with pattern `##-####` and copy it into next column, example below:

[image: Example]

Can somebody help me?

```
Sub Pull_6_Digit_Numbers_From_String()


   Dim r As Range, i As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\b\d{6}\b"
        For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If .test(r.Value) Then
                For i = 0 To .Execute(r.Value).Count - 1
                    r(, i + 2).Value = .Execute(r.Value)(i)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to extend your current pattern? Try `\b\d{2}-?\d{4}\b`

Comment: Are you having trouble coming up with the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current pattern, `\b\d{6}\b`, matches a word boundary, then 6 consecutive digits and then again a word boundary. So, it matches `123456` in `text 123456 here`. To also match `12-3456`, you may split the pattern into 2- and 4-digit subpatterns and insert an optional `-` pattern, `-?`.

```
\b\d{2}-?\d{4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BWNSXg/1)

The `-?` matches 1 or 0 hyphens, and `\d{2}` with `\d{4}` will match 6 digits between word boundaries all in all.

Comment: Got it, Thank you Wiktor for clear and transparent explanation!

Comment: Wiktor, is there a way to pull the text with starts with capital N and will have combination of 3 to 6 letters or numbers with it ie.  N24 or NX747 or N35655V but it should ignore N2 or N8(N plus 1 character) or N1234567(N plus more than 6 characters?

Comment: @FotoDJ: It seems you want either [`\bN[^\W_]{3,6}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/BWNSXg/2) or [`\bN[^\W_]{2,6}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/BWNSXg/3).

Comment: \bN[^\W_]{3,6}\b solves the problem, thanks a lot!   it matches also N and lower case words like North, New etc, Is there a way to prevent matching lower case after N which would eliminate above matching problem, I promise this is the last question, you 've been a great help, Wiktor.

Comment: `\bN(?![a-z])[^\W_]{3,6}\b`

Comment: It is brilliant again.THANK YOU.